# How to augment anonymous type object in C#

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

I often need to augment a object with a property for instance. Until now (tired of it ;) and it's ugly too) I have done it this way:

```
var someListOfObjects = ...;

var objectsWithMyProperty = from o in someListOfObjects
                            select new
                            {
                                o.Name,    /* Just copying all the attributes I need */
                                o.Address, /* which may be all of them. */

                                SomeNewProperty = value
                            };
```

Is there a clever way to do this? What I have done previously is something like this:

```
var objectsWithMyProperty = from o in someListOfObjects
                            select new
                            {
                                OldObject = o,           /* I access all of the old properties from here */    
                                SomeNewProperty = value
                            };
```

I guess this could be done with some reflection, but I imagine there is a faster approach which makes something equivalent to the first cumbersome approach.

Thanks, Lasse

Comment: I guess you could dish up a fancy Expression tree. But it will probably not work for Linq2SQL and friends.

Comment: What's the problem with the second approach?

Comment: @Pieter I think it is ugly and ain't making sense in the context I use it in. Fx if you supply it as a datasource you end up with `Eval("WhyDoIHaveToHaveANameHere.TheActualProperty")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is something like the ExpandoObject that was added in C# 4.0 along with the dynamic type

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff796227.aspx

Internally it uses a dictionary so you can add/remove members dynamically. The first time you try to access a property like:

```
obj.NewProperty = newValue
```

the ExpandoObject will automatically add this to its internal dictionary.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Now you mention the `ExpandoObject` I recall that I have the magazine you link to. I would have preferred a static solution but a dynamic is better than none :) Thanks...

Answer (score 4):

No there is no support for appending new properties to an existing anonymous type.  An anonymous type expression can only be used to create a brand new anonymous type with the specified properties.  The two best alternatives for appending new properties are the ones listed in the question.

Comment: That's too bad :( Thanks... :)